Flutter POST request not being recieved on server side
Trying to send an image from Flutter application to python Flask project using HTTP POST request, but the server log does not register any POST requests being made.
Flutter client side code is making a POST request like this
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () async {
        final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
        var image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
        File file = File(image!.path); 
              
        var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:5000/'));
        request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('imagefile', file.path));
        var data = await request.send;

                       
        print("request: " + request.toString());

This is printed to console when I run
flutter: request: POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/

But on the server side log Flask is not receiving a POST request. The log looks like this
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Apr/2024 11:51:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 405 -

Flask server side code looks like this
@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def home():

    if 'imagefile' not in request.files:
        return 'File Not Found'
        
    try:
        imagefile = request.files.get['imagefile']
        
        if imagefile.filename == '':
            return 'No File Selected'

        # image manipulation code that i don't think is relevent to the issue 

        return 'Done'
    
    except Exception as e:
        return f'Error: {e}'
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()


I can see a couple of issues in the given code.

If you are running the app on an Android emulator and you are running the Flask server on your laptop/pc you can't access the API with 127.0.0.1. Android Emulator uses 10.0.2.2 pointing to the localhost.

Are you sure you're calling the request.send method? The following line just acts as a reference to the send method, it doesn't seem to call/invoke the send method.


 var data = await request.send;

Here's a corrected version of your code:
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () async {
        final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
        var image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
        File file = File(image!.path); 
              
        var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:5000/'));
        request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('imagefile', file.path));
        var data = await request.send();

                       
        print("request: " + request.toString());
   },
   // ...
)

Edit:
This answer is based on the assumption that you are using Android Emulator to test your app since you haven't mentioned it in the original question, if that's not the case and you're testing your app on a real device: please refer to this answer and make sure your URI is correct.
Hope this helps :)
